# Is there a snip tool (Windows) equivalent for ubuntu?

Tags: screenshot

Is there a snipping tool similar to the one in Windows which lets you view it even though you haven't saved anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ksnip

ksnip is pretty much exactly like the Windows snipping tool. The UI looks very alike and you would use it in the same way.

You can install via `snap` with:

```
sudo snap install ksnip
```

The source code and other installation options can be found on [their GitHub page](https://github.com/ksnip/ksnip).

Here are some screenshots of ksnip:
[image: ksnip before capture]

[image: ksnip with capture]

To get more answers you might also want to try the SE site [Software Reccomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @user1141101 You are very welcome!

Comment: very good but I preferred install it from .deb file fo avoid snaps that I've disinstalled from my system. Downloaded .deb file from here : https://github.com/ksnip/ksnip/releases

Comment: @pat Thank you for the comment, I have added the GitHub page to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly what you mean, because I don't use any windows snipping tool.
I use "Screenshot 3.36.0" (install package gnome-screenshot). Which I have bound to the "print-screen"-button.
Which this you can copy the screen (or window) to the clipboard or save to file.